# Search a directory of tarballs for a file?

Tags: linux, command, find

So I have a directory of tarballs. i.e /home/username/dir_w_tarballs. In one of those tarballs is a license key from an engineer that used to work here. How can I search across each of the tarballs in the directory for a specific file? Something similar to `find . -name some_file`? I know I can search a single tarball with `tar -jtvf file.tar.bz2`. I am hoping for something a bit broader in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
find -name '*.tar' -o -name '*.tar.*' | while read f; do
    tar -tf "$f" | grep some_file | sed "s|^|$f:|"
done
```

It will recursively find all tarballs under the current directory, list each one of them, use `grep` to search for a specific file and then `sed` to prepend the tarball name to each match so that you would be able to tell which tarball contains each match...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Doesnt seem to work for me. I enter it all as a one line command, like this

Comment: @Houdini: this also assumes a reasonably recent `tar` version that can decompress tarballs without explicit `-z`/`-j` options...

Comment: Sorry my last post got messed up. I cant figure out how to use highlight code in the response window, but basically I enter this as one line (now with the extra semi-colon):                     find -name '*.tar' -o -name '*.tar.*' | while read f; do tar -tf "$f" | grep libncui.so | sed "s|^|$f:|" ; done

Comment: tar-1.26 should be fine. Which shell are you using? This snippet is for `bash`...

Comment: I am using bash. I understand the logic of what you're trying to do, but I am not a strong enough Linux user to figure out if I am doing something wrong. I will ask one of the senior engineers tomorrow about your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @Houdini: your one-liner (plus the `*` that got lost in the translation) works fine for me...

Comment: Thanks for your tip of the `code`. And I got your bash working this morning, one of the senior engineers suggested adding a `echo $f;` after the `do`. That way you can see where the file was found. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a specific file or pattern using tar and grep command and bash for loop. Just change < pattern >:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; 
do echo $i; 
tar tf $i| grep <pattern>; 
echo '------------'; 
done
```

It goes through every file in the folder and extracts only tree content and grep through them.

If you want to search recursively:

```
find . -type f -name "*.tar.gz" | while read f; do echo $f; tar tf $f| grep db_dump ;done
```